# Discord Py 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

By using this code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord


class Voice(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(name='join')
    async def join(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
        print(str(channel))



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Voice(client))
```

Can't find why it doesn't work :/
I watched a yt video with exactly the same code, but there it worked ...

Comment: don't have client and bot, only use client ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the author can use this command although he is not in a voice channel and then he doesn't have a voice object.
you can use try and except or if to check if the voice object is empty.